# Insert sub image to my thesis by latex

Tags: graphics, classicthesis

I trying to add image to the left-notes of page using classicthesis theme with latex.

But I'm beginner with latex, so no have enough experiment to search and find yourself solutions(I search it solutions over 3h but it fails). 
[image: The image show my need latex code for]

How do I can make a note image like that.

Comment: It seems that `changepage` package can help you, however without seeing MWE (Minimal Working Example) which reproduce your document layout and show what you try so far, is impossible to help you. Or this is jusz an image in page border of your document not tied to showed tables?

Comment: Assuming \marginparwidth is large enough, you can use `\marginpar` to insert text or images.  You can also use `\captionof{figure}{...}` from the caption or capt-of packages (or just use `\expandafter\def\csname @captype\endcsname{figure}`).

Comment: For this layout of margin figures consider use the `tufte-book` class instead of  classicthesis. Run `texdoc tufte` (page 23).